# SQL Server : remove redundant rows where same room in sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server

Have data that tracks a person movements through beds, e.g

```
PersonSK   ArrivalDttm          Room    Sequence 
------------------------------------------------
11111      01/01/2015 15:00     Bed 1       1
11111      01/01/2015 18:00     Bed 1       2
11111      01/01/2015 21:00     Bed 1       3
11111      01/01/2015 22:00     Bed 7       4
```

Desired output is

```
PersonSK   ArrivalDttm          Room    Sequence  Departure dttm
----------------------------------------------------------------
11111      01/01/2015 15:00     Bed 1       1     01/01/2015 22:00
11111      01/01/2015 22:00     Bed 7       2     NULL
```

Can't think of a way to do this, the logic I want to impose is the following:

- Select min sequence/arrival dttm where bed number changes but all previous beds in sequence were the same as the first

Update: My actual solution based on answers provided

```
WITH cte_bed_moves as (

SELECT
 movements.[Facility (Location)]
,movements.[Person Id]
,movements.[Visit Id]
,movements.[Room (Tracking Location)]
,movements.[Location Sequence Number] 
,movements.[Arrival to Location Dt/Tm] as arrival_dttm
,min_next_bed.arrival_dttm as end_dttm
FROM 
edcs_firstnet_bed_movements AS movements OUTER APPLY 
(/*Find next bed that is not the same type as the current*/
SELECT MIN(apply_nextBed.[Arrival to Location Dt/Tm]) as arrival_dttm
FROM edcs_firstnet_bed_movements AS apply_nextBed
WHERE
    movements.[Facility (Location)] = apply_nextBed.[Facility (Location)]
    AND movements.[Person Id] = apply_nextBed.[Person Id]
    AND movements.[Visit Id] = apply_nextBed.[Visit Id]
    AND apply_nextBed.[Location Sequence Number] > movements.[Location       Sequence Number]
    AND apply_nextBed.[Room (Tracking Location)] <> movements.[Room (Tracking Location)]
 ) as min_next_bed
)

/*for each bed, get rid of the duplicates with times inbetween*/
select 
 [Facility (Location)] as facility_name
,[Person Id] as person_id
,[Visit Id] as ed_visit_id
,[Room (Tracking Location)] as room
,end_dttm
,min(arrival_dttm) as arrival_dttm
from cte_bed_moves
group by
[Facility (Location)]
,[Person Id]
,[Visit Id]
,[Room (Tracking Location)]
,end_dttm
```

Comment: Your output doesn't make sense to me. Why are you displaying the time from Bed 7 on the row for Bed 1? What you really need to do is post ddl and sample data (sqlfiddle.com is a decent location for this) and desired output based on your sample data.

Comment: It's all possible with use of analytic functions and joins. I've done that before some times but can't find the time to present you the answer atm. If nobody will point you in the right direction I'll try to find the time tomorrow.

Comment: Under it it states "With the last column been the departure dttm", i.e bed 1's departure time is beds 7's arrival time, updated question to be more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your table is named `person_dttm` the following should work:

```
SELECT arr.PersonSK, MIN(arr.ArrivalDttm) as StartDttm,
(SELECT MIN(p2.ArrivalDttm)
 FROM person_dttm p2 
 WHERE p2.PersonSK=arr.PersonSK AND p2.ArrivalDttm > arr.ArrivalDttm AND p2.Room <> arr.Room) as EndDttm
FROM person_dttm arr
GROUP BY arr.PersonSK, arr.Room
ORDER BY arr.PersonSK, arr.ArrivalDttm
```

The basic idea is to select the list people and their earliest arrival in each room. Then add a subquery which selects the minimum arrival time of all the records of that same patient, excluding rows for the same room and excluding rows that happened earlier.

Comment: ahh much better/easier way of thinking of it,  "For each bed find the min arrival time of the next bed that is not the current one". Thanks :)

Comment: Won't let me edit to  add "and keep the min arrival for each bed"

Comment: Incidentally I wasn't sure if the Sequence column was per-patient visit or per table. So I opted to use only the date, i.e. (p2.ArrivalDttm > arr.ArrivalDttm AND p2.Room <> arr.Room).  If each PersonSK gets its own sequence with no gaps (e.g. 1,2,3,..) then you could replace that clause with (p2.Sequence=arr.Sequence+1) and it would be more efficient. I see at least one other answer using that trick. OTOH sequence then has to be maintained for all the patient's rows if someone edits a date, or inserts or deletes a time mid-visit. Using ArrivalDttm is arguably more foolproof.

Answer (score 0):

Join table on itself using neighbour rows:

```
SELECT T1.ArrivalDttm ArrivalDttm, T2.ArrivalDttm DepartureDttm, ...
FROM T AS T1
LEFT JOIN T AS T2 ON
  T1.PersonSK = T2.PersonSK AND T1.sequence + 1 = T2.sequence
...
WHERE
  T1.Room != T2.Room
```

After that you will have to calculate new sequence number, the easiest way would be to join on subquery again:

```
... T3.sequence sequence
...
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT tmp.Room) AS sequence, tmp.PersonSK
  FROM T AS tmp
  WHERE tmp.ArrivalDttm <= T1.ArrivalDttm AND tmp.PersonSK = T1.PersonSK
) T3 ON T1.PersonSK = T3.PersonSK
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my two cents using Analytic Functions:

```
select b.PersonSK, 
       b2.ArrivalDttm,
       b.Room,
       row_number() over (partition by b.PersonSk 
                           order by b2.ArrivalDttm) as "Sequence",
       lead(b2.ArrivalDttm) over (partition by b.PersonSk 
                                   order by b2.ArrivalDttm) as "Departure dttm"
  from beds b
        INNER JOIN 
         (SELECT PersonSK,
                 room, 
                 min(ArrivalDttm) ArrivalDttm
            FROM beds
           GROUP by PersonSK, room) b2 
        ON b.PersonSK = b2.PersonSK
           AND b.room = b2.room
           AND b.ArrivalDttm = b2.ArrivalDttm
```

As `Sequence` is a reserved word you need to wrap it with double quotes. The same with `"Departure dttm"` because you can't have an alias with a space.

Here it is working on SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4940a/1

Note that I made it with postgresql because sqlserver was unstable. The sintaxe is the same.